# Missing space after Appendix

Tags: spacing, elsarticle

I am working on a document that has an appendix. I would like it to have the heading: "**Appendix A. Tasks for Progressive Formulation**"

This is the code I am using

```
 \appendix

 \newpage

 \section{Tasks for Progressive Formulation}
```

The result I get is missing the space between the word Appendix and the letter A. It shows like this:

**AppendixA. Tasks for Progressive Formulation**

How can I force a white space between Appendix and the letter?

Edit: more code

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}

\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage[autostyle, english = american]{csquotes} 
\usepackage{float} 
\restylefloat{figure} 
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{lineno} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{natbib} 
\usepackage{tabulary} 


\begin{document}

\appendix
\newpage
\section{Tasks for Progressive Formulation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

It's a wrong choice by `elsarticle.cls` that has

```
\def\appendixname{Appendix }
```

with a space, whereas `babel` correctly does

```
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Appendix}
```

with no space. You can reinstate the behavior expected by `elsarticle` doing

```
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Appendix }}
```

Here's a minimal example (the other packages you load have nothing to do with the issue)
But, really, `elsarticle` should do di
    \documentclass{elsarticle}

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Appendix }}

\begin{document}

\appendix
\section{Tasks for Progressive Formulation}
\end{document}
```

---

But, really, `elsarticle` should do differently: the code from line 748 to line 758 in `elsarticle.cls` should be

```
\renewcommand\appendix{\par
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \setcounter{subsection}{0}%
  \setcounter{equation}{0}
  \gdef\thefigure{\@Alph\c@section.\arabic{figure}}%
  \gdef\thetable{\@Alph\c@section.\arabic{table}}%
  \gdef\thesection{\appendixname\space\@Alph\c@section}%
  \@addtoreset{equation}{section}%
  \gdef\theequation{\@Alph\c@section.\arabic{equation}}%
}
```

without a redefinition of `\appendixname` and adding the space in the redefinition of `\thesection`. A fixed tag should be just a tag, with no “formatting instructions” that belong elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following MWE (I reduced your code a little bit to make it minimal):

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}

\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry} 

\usepackage{blindtext}  % dummy text


\begin{document}
\blindtext % dummy text
\appendix
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\appendixname~\Alph{section}}
\section{Tasks for Progressive Formulation}
\blindtext
\subsection{Test}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

The point for you is the line `\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\appendixname~\Alph{section}}`. here I redefine the error in your used document class.  `\appendixname` gives "Appendix" and `\Alph{section}` contains the numbering (A) and the heading.  `\thesection` is the macro that writes the wrong line and is redefined with `\renewcommand`.

Result:

[image]